# How to share variables between functions in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm learning Vue and trying to test out how I'd pass a user input from one function to another.

My use case is this. I want to take a users input, store it and then supply that to a second function as a variable that it can use to make an API call.

In isolation the two code sections are:

**User Input**

```
<div id="v-model-basic" class="demo">
  <input v-model="message" placeholder="edit me" />
  <p>Message is: {{ message }}</p>
</div>

Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      message: ''
    }
  }
}).mount('#v-model-basic')
```

**API Call**

```
import axios from 'axios';

/* API call for the weather data */
export default {
  name: "Weather",
  data() {
    return {
      weatherList: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
   getweatherData() {
      axios.get("https://anAPIpath.com/that-I-want-to-add-user-input-to").then(response => (this.weatherList = response.data));
    }
  }  
};
```

Is there a way to do this in Vue where they are both methods within that export function, or is that just the wrong approach? As mentioned, new and learning Vue and I want to ensure I approach this the "Vue way" so things are as neat and tidy as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue has several options for passing variables between components.

#### `props`

You can make the variable a prop of the other:

```
props: {
  message: String
}
```

The prop is accessed with `this.message` but it is recommended you copy it to a variable in `data` and reflect changes with `$emit` (see documentation link, and `$emit` section below).

See documentation: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#props

#### `$emit`

You can let a parent component know about the other component's changes with `$emit`. You can just name an event yourself and pass the value as the first parameter.

```
this.$emit('messageUpdate', this.message);
```

See documentation: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/emits-option.html#emits-option

#### VueX

With the VueX data storage you can transfer variables from any component across your app to any other.
This takes a little more finess to set up. I suggest going with the above first.

If you are interested (definitely worth to learn), here is the link:
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/#getting-started

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't just want the answer. I want to understand why the answer is the answer. Looking forward to reading through the docs and learning more about these options!

Comment: Yes the docs will definitely help  I also recommend searching for some tutorials for all of those - I just don't want to play favorites and only link to the official docs. Tutorials can help a lot as well. Mark this as answer if you're satisfied, otherwise I can go into more detail if you need.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are doing well, you just need to add the API call to a script tag in the same file and then access the input message like this:

```
axios.get("https://anAPIpath.com/"+ this.message)
```