# Copy a URL from a data sent into the function with VueJs (NOT FROM A CLIPBOARD)

Tags: vue.js

Hi I want to create a copy button with VueJs... I do not need to copy from a clipboard, textarea, or anything like that... I just want to pass into the function the dynamic url that I created and I want to copy that dynamic url that I send into the funcion.

I have a code like this:

```
<button v-on:click="copyUrl('dynamic_url')" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-sm">
    <i class="fas fa-copy"></i>
</button>
```

And my Vuejs code:

```
 vuecopydemo(dynamic_url) {
    document.execCommand('copy');
 },
```

How you can see I do not know what I need to add in the VueJs method to catch or copy that dynamic url that I sent into the function..

How can I do that?  Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share variables between functions in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70021965/how-to-share-variables-between-functions-in-vue)

Comment: @PeterKrebs no ti does not answer my question because I need to copy the url to paste in any place that I want I mean I want to send thta url through whatsapp or email.. etc